# Rails 3 ActiveRecord eager loading of scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Help me please.
I have some model which has_many association with other model.
For example: profile => has_many :statistics
And inside of statistic model I have some scope:

```
scope last_ten, limit(10).order('online desc')
```

And question is how can I use eager load for this scope? I don't need every record of statistics for profile. Only scoped.

Now I can use only

```
 User.profiles.includes(:statistics)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

As explained here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

It's better to define a custom relation:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :most_recent_stats, :class_name => 'Statistic', :order => 'online DESC', :limit => 10
  ...
end

User.profiles.includes(:most_recent_stats)
```

Comment: In the above case all statistics belongs to profile will be loaded. In eager loading limit will be discarded as per the document http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: And there is no way to load only needed records? Seems like I will always have n+1 problem or load all objects into memory? And what it will be if i have more than thousands of records?
What can I do?!