# Can any one help me how to do eager loading with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Example:

```
has_many : comments
belongs_to : user
scope : more_no comments where(self.no_times >10)
```

Query:like this i tried

```
User.includes(:comments).all.collect{|u| u.comments.more_no_comments}
```

but iterating multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a custom association instead of the scope and use this for eager loading:

```
has_many :more_no_comments, :class_name => 'Comment', -> { where "no_times > 10" }
```

and then

```
User.includes(:more_no_comments).all.collect{|u| u.comments.more_no_comments}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937759/rails-3-activerecord-eager-loading-of-scope).

Comment: `includes` works on associations of the model, scopes are defined on the *associated* model