# Rails includes with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, rails-activerecord

I have a model called Author. An author has many Articles.
Articles have a scope called .published that does: where(published: true).

I want to load the author, with the published articles.
I tried:

```
Author.includes(:articles.published).find(params[:author_id])
```

But that throws an error: undefined method 'published'.
Any idea?

Comment: Yep, this just has to be searched with a bit different terms. This is "eager loading of scoped association", see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937759/rails-3-activerecord-eager-loading-of-scope ...and this turns out to be duplicate?

Answer (score 63):

I think the best solution would be:

```
Author.includes(:articles).where(:articles=>{published: true}).find(params[:author_id])
```

Or you can create scope:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base 
    scope :with_published_articles, -> { includes(:articles).where(articles: { published: true}) }
end
```

and then:

```
Author.with_published_articles.find(params[:author_id].to_s)
```

Answer (score 28):

I would specify a scope on the `Author` called `with_published_articles` like this:

```
scope :with_published_articles, -> { joins(:articles).merge(Article.published) }
```

This will resolve your problem to also specify the `where(active: true)` on your `Author` model in case the `published` behaviour of and `Article` will change in the future.

So now you can call:

```
Author.with_published_articles.find(params[:author_id])
```

Comment: This is the best answer since it doesn't couple Author with Article's internal implementation of what "published" means

Comment: As far as I know joins does not eager load, so this will still have n+1 problem

Comment: This is the correct answer because it decreases future cost-of-change (avoiding code duplication and leaking implementation details of the concept of a published Article). And as tantrix said, it also avoids further coupling of Author and Article.

Answer (score 5):

Try this code:

```
Author
  .includes(:articles).where(published: true).references(:articles)
  .find(params[:author_id])
```

Here you can find more information about the example above:
[includes api doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes)

Answer (score 5):

Using:

```
class Articles < ActiveRecord::Base 
    scope :published, -> { where(articles: {published: true}) }
end
```

Define a scope on Autor

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base 
    scope :with_published_articles, -> { joins(:articles).merge(Articles.published) }
end
```

Or

```
Author.joins(:articles).merge(Articles.published).find(params[:author_id])
```