# Can I use scopes on an included model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have scopes defined on my Job model, and I want to use them when including jobs in an Active Record query, rather than writing out long-hand the conditions and ordering.

Here is the code I have that works but is very verbose:

```
@employees_and_jobs = supervisor.direct_reports.alphabetical \
.includes(:jobs) \
.where('jobs.active = true') \
.order('jobs.record_number asc, jobs.effective_date asc')
```

Here is the code I wish would work:

```
@employees_and_jobs = supervisor.direct_reports.alphabetical.includes(:jobs).active.sorted
```

The scopes `direct_reports` and `alphabetical` work, but the others (`active` and `sorted`) are interpreted as belonging to the `Employee` model, and give me an error.  I want `active` and `sorted` to be interpreted as belonging to the `Job` model.   How can I change the query to show that `active` and `sorted` are scopes for `Job` and not `Employee`?

The `active` and `sorted` scopes are of course defined on the Job model, and are done with an explicit reference to jobs (but of course that is not enough):

```
scope :sorted, -> { order('jobs.record_number asc, jobs.effective_date asc') }
scope :active, -> { where('jobs.active = true') }
```

(I didn't expect the explicit reference to `jobs` inside the scope to make it work, but I tried it just in case, and mention it in case someone else thinks it might work.)

How can I specify in my query that the final scopes are meant to apply to the included jobs, and not to the employees?

(I realize I can solve the problem with a default scope, but that can create new problems later, and I'm trying to avoid that.  I would prefer the verbose version above over using a default scope.)

### Similar (But Different) Questions

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26159533/241142) don't answer my question, but simply instead offer an alternative approach to dealing with the situation.  (But I already *have* an alternative approach, given above.  I have working code, but I'm trying to improve readability in a very particular way by using scopes on not just the main model but also the included model.)

I'm asking for a way to use scopes ***on the included model*** but those answers explain how to use a scope ***on** the main model* that in turn ***includes the other model***.  Two ***very different*** things.  They are similar in that they both make the controller code simpler but the other approach makes the controller potentially less clear.  It just moving all of the complexity into a single scope which would (in my case) be on the Employee model.  I'm aiming to have have very specific scopes that I can compose together, which each have a very clear and clearly defined purpose.

Comment: Why isn't working? Any log, error? What's the result of `supervisor.direct_reports.alphabetical`, if it's not a `Job::ActiveRecord_Relation` object that's gonna throw `NoMethodError`.

Comment: The scopes `direct_reports` and `alphabetical` work, but the others (`active` and `sorted`) are interpreted as belonging to the `Employee` model, and give me an error.  I want `active` and `sorted` to be interpreted as belonging to the `Job` model.   How can I change the query to show that `active` and `sorted` are scopes for `Job` and not `Employee`?

Comment: @SebastianPalma: I updated my question to include the clarification of my last comment...

Comment: Just add .references(:jobs) at the end so it knows which table you're referring to via the includes.  Check out more info on it here: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails includes with scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159533/rails-includes-with-scope)

Comment: @engineersmnky: no, that doesn't answer my question, but it is an alternative approach to dealing with the situation.  If what I'm asking for turns out to be impossible (using scopes _**on the included model**_) then I might do that instead (use a scope _**on** the main model_ that in turn _**includes the other model**_) since it also makes the controller code clean, although I don't think it's nearly as ideal as what I'm aiming for.  In a way it just moves the verbosity into a scope.  I'd rather have very specific scopes that I compose together, not one large scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`scope`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope) is really just syntactic sugar for defining class methods. So like any other class method you can just call your scopes on the class which defines them:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employee
  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
  scope :sorted, -> { order('jobs.record_number asc, jobs.effective_date asc') }
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :jobs
   scope :with_active_jobs, ->{ include(:jobs).merge(Job.active).merge(Job.sorted) }
end
```

[ActiveRecord::SpawnMethods#merge](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge) is probably one of the most underused features of AR. It lets you mash different scopes together programatically.

ActiveRecord is smart enough to specify the table with `.where` so there is not problem in using it in a join (`.where('jobs.active = true')` will also work fine too). Unfortunately `.order` is not as smart and `.order(record_number: :asc, effective_date: :asc)` will generate `ORDER BY record_number ASC, effective_date ASC` which will give an error.

There is no technical reason you have to do this in the model either. You can just do `Employee.include(:jobs).merge(Job.active).merge(Job.sorted)` or whatever in the controller if you want to compose the scopes there. But remember that controllers are really difficult to test compared to models.

Comment: Seems you could also possibly do `merge(->{Job.active.sorted})`?

Comment: @engineersmnky yeah. Why the lambda though?

Comment: Just because you can 