# A has_one psudorelationship that returns the last of a has_many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to make an association on `Model` class. `Model` `has_many` `OtherModel`s. I want to make an association on `Model` `has_one :last_other_model`.

The best I can think to do is to do `has_one :last_other_model, class: 'OtherModel', limit: 1` -- but `has_one` does not accept a `limit`.

Any ideas?

Comment: could you use a scope? or even a method that returns an activerecord relation? why does it need to be an association?

Comment: Eager loading it, I don't believe you can eager load scopes (but I could be wrong).

Comment: Searching for eager loading scopes has led to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937759/rails-3-activerecord-eager-loading-of-scope which seems to do what I am trying to do but with `has_many`. That might be the only way to do this cleanly; but question stands in case someone has a clever way of doing this :]

Comment: Ahh, but rails says that eager loading will ignore limits on has_many, which would defeat the purpose:
> If you eager load an association with a specified :limit option, it will be ignored, returning all the associated objects:

Answer (score 3):

Rails 4, try:

```
has_one :last_other_model, ->{ order 'some_field asc'}, class_name: 'OtherModel'
```

The second parameter is a lambda in which block you can call any ActiveRecord method to filter and sort, Rails will return the first of that collection, without needing to use `limit`.

You can translate this to Rails 3 and 2 too, with a skightly different syntax of course.